# Wait loops to return a value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, async-await

This code should empty the array, but since the amount of data is so large, it can not empty it, and the function has already returned the value.

The while loop, when working with such a large array, takes more time than it takes the function to return the value.

So, I need to wait for the cycle, to return the expected value, how should it be done?

```
 function a(max) {

var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(max)).map((cur, index) => index),
    l = arr.length,
    acc = 0;

    while(acc < l) {
    arr.splice(acc, 1);
    acc++;
    }
  return arr;
}

console.log(a(100000).length);
```

So, how can I wait for the while to be executed? , I guess I should do something with await, promises or callbacks, but I'm still new to asynchronous functions and executions.

PD: I read about generators, await, async , but i not know what i should use and how to apply them.

This isnt code problem, with 100 or 1000 elements the code works fine, but with 100000 the while loop takes more time , so the main function return the value before of finished the while loop.

**I want to return the arr, when, and only when, the array has been emptied COMPLETELY.**

Another try:

```
function a() {
 var flag = false, acc = 0;
  while(acc > 100000) {
    flag = true;
  }
  return flag;
}

console.log(a())
```

want to return the value, when and only when, the while cycle has finished, so the function should return true

Comment: what is the purpose of this line `Array.apply(null, Array(max)).map((cur, index) => index)`?

Comment: There are no async operations in your function. Something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: Generate an array of max length and iterate through it , and fill it with 0 - max - 1 @brk

Comment: I have not said that I have asynchronous operations, I just need to wait for the while cycle, to return the value, since being such a large array, the while takes more time, than it takes the function to the return statement

Comment: JavaScript as a whole is not asynchronous by nature. Only certain elements of it are, such as API calls and functions that involve the event loop, such as `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. Your code never finishes because your conditional inside your while will never become false.

Comment: fixed, was acc++ instead of -- , but the problem isnt this

Comment: There may be some level of confusion about what sync and async is. An async operation is the only way for something below one line of code to finish before the one above it. Again, the issue is in your code. Think about what  is happening when you continually `splice` and what your `acc` variable will be as you continually remove elements from your array. Remember you're mutating the array each time you run `splice`. Your indexes for each respective value changes.

Comment: It's not that, it's definitely an asynchronous topic. If you test with 1000 elements, the time is smaller and reaches to return what was expected. But if, the array has 10e6 elements or more, the time becomes bigger, and it does not return as expected.

Comment: The array, is just an example, what happens within the cycle is totally irrelevant. The real problem is, to return the value when and ONLY WHEN, the while cycle has finished completely.

Comment: See my last example please, HMR

Comment: Your last example also does not make any sense. Maybe you could just explain what you want your code to do instead of providing code that don't make sense. Leave some code in there with `I tried this so far` or people will down vote you (don't worry about down vote too much, you can remove the question later and you get your points back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking the issue. Your problem is how you're implementing `splice`. What does the `acc` variable become as your while loop iterates. If your `max` is 100, do you agree that at some point, your `acc` will equal `99`? Your splice would then be run as `arr.splice(99, 1)`. That's an inverted index range, which has no proper meaning. JavaScript won't throw an error when you try and do that, because it is evil.

What you should be doing instead, is repeatedly splicing the first element off, which is at index 0. It is always at index 0, because you are mutating your array each time you run `spice`. This is the code you're looking for. I made some modifications, for brevity.

```js
function a(max) {
  const arr = [...Array(max)].map((_, idx) => idx)
  const arrLength = arr.length
  let acc = 0
  while (acc < arrLength) {
    arr.splice(0, 1)
    acc++
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(a(10000))
```

This code is synchronous. Yes, JavaScript has special concepts that require things like `Promise`s, but this is not one of them. Now that you have this code, a `max` of `10e6` will cause the function to never finish, because the operation is too time consuming. Your browser will lock up if you try. Even 10000 is relatively slow.

Edit:
I promise you that these are synchronous operations. Why are you so insistent that they are not? For your new code, it is missing multiple things. First, `acc > 100000` will instantly return false and skip your loop. Second, you never increment your `acc`. Here is this code, fixed.

```js
function flagTest() {
 var flag = false, acc = 0;
  while(acc < 100000) {
    flag = true;
    acc++
  }
  return flag;
}

console.log(flagTest())
```

Comment: @HMR His overall attempt is to take an array of numbers and emptying the array. That's what the first statement in his question says

Comment: @HMR I'm not questioning his methods and ultimate goal of this function. I'm just telling him what he did incorrectly that is causing an unexpected output. His line of logic is correct: he is emptying an array by iterating by using `splice`. He's just implementing it incorrectly and is coming to incorrect conclusions as to why.

Comment: This has nothing to do, in addition it returns the complete matrix if you use 100000 elements, That is my problem, I hope that I really empty all the elements and then return.

Comment: Wait for the while loop to finish, and when, and ONLY WHEN, it is finished, the function can return the value

Comment: Carlos, your `console.log(a(100).length)` returns 50 because it fundamentally does not work. This is not an issue with async.

Comment: It's quite complicated for me, explain in English.

But I have put a new example code, so you can see my real problem.

Comment: Updated to answer your next problem. @carloscerdadiaz why are you so insistent that these are async operations? Every issue that has happened so far has been incorrect code. Type the exact logic you have in any other programming language. They will return the same thing.